# How to avoid warning "Cannot resolve configuration property" in Intellij and Apache Camel properties placeholder

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, apache-camel

In my Spring Boot Apache Camel project I use placeholders to `application.properties` like

```
from("timer:myTimer?period={{timer.period}}")
```

Intellij gives me a warning `"Cannot resolve configuration property 'timer.period'"`. In the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html) there is a solution how to generate metadata for custom properties. Unfortunately this seems to work for `@Value` annotation only.

Is there an option how to generate `spring-configuration-metadata.json` from the `{{...}}` placeholders automaticaly or do I have to do it manually?

EDIT:
The line in the `application.properties` file that gives the warning is

```
timer.period = 2000
```

The entire demo project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/jirmed/camel-rabbitmq-exceptionshttps://)

Comment: Can you provide also application.properties file with which you are running the application?

Comment: I have added the application.properties line and a link to GitHub to the original question